# Grails Spring Security can't see flash message on authentication failure

Tags: grails, spring-security

I'm trying to implement something that should be very simple. However, I can't seem to get it working.

I've implemented custom form login, and I'm trying to display the error message on authentication failed.

After Authentication fails. I'm taken to the `grails.plugin.springsecurity.LoginController.authfail()` method. It loads the exception message and sets it as a `flash` message.

```
if (springSecurityService.isAjax(request)) {
    render([error: msg] as JSON)
}
else {
    flash.message = msg
    redirect action: 'auth', params: params
}
```

After this, I'm redirected back to the login page with the following URL:

```
http://localhost:9090/lm/login/auth?login_error=1
```

In my `auth.gsp` file. I've added the following code to display the flash message.

```
<g:message code="${flash.message}" args="${flash.args}" default="${flash.default}"/>
```

However nothing is being displayed on the login page upon redirect. What could be the problem with this?

Here are the DEBUG logs from Spring Security when I attempt authentication.
http://pastebin.com/z7sU4ipQ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<g:message code="${flash.message}" args="${flash.args}" default="${flash.default}"/>
```

The line above treating that the `flash.message` should be a message code and if there is no code found then it should use the `flash.default` as the default value which is also not available.

Considering, your login failed due to bad credential so your `flash.message` message will have a message like `No account found with this username and password`. When you render this `flash.message` into your GSP to the `g:message code`, of course there is no message code defined so it will look for `flash.default`. But there is no value in `flash.default` so you are not seeing anything.

So, either replace that line simply with `${flash.message}` or change that like:

```
<g:message code="${flash.message}" args="${flash.args}" default="${flash.message}"/>
```